# Reading data off text file and using methods to calculate and to display certain values (Basic JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

So this is a plead for some help to send me in the right path. 
I know the basics of java Script. i have done a few courses including code academy and [Foundations of Programming: Fundamentals](https://www.lynda.com/Programming-Foundations-tutorials/Foundations-Programming-Fundamentals/83603-2.html).

So for this semester at uni we have to read a file(.txt) using java-script and then create some methods to calculate some values,string ect then display that on an html site.

I need some help from you guys to point me in the right direction, about some resources that will help me learn how to do this.

Things i know i have to learn:

- Push data from .txt to file to array. (I think the indiviual data will be separated by special character (e.g: / ,)
- How to get data from that array and then use it in an method to calculate values or string values.
- I also need a good resource to learn about creating methods.

I attach code that already does this but i what to **understanding how it works.** This is one of the reasons why i cant do it on my own.

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask but thanks for reading. :)

Javascript code:

```
    var loadedHandler = function (event) {
  // console.log("file has loaded")
  // console.log(event.target.result);
  var user = event.target.result.split('\r\n');
  console.log(user);
  // console.log("here 3");

  localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify({username: user[0], password: user[1]}));
  var result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
  console.log(result);
};

// define the reaction when change event happens
var fileChangeHandler = function (event) {
  "use strict";  
  // console.log("file has changed!")
  var reader = new FileReader();  
  reader.onload = loadedHandler;

  // console.log("here 1");
  var theFile = event.target.files[0];
  reader.readAsText(theFile);
  // console.log("here 2");
};
```

Html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="simpleLoader.js">
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    // create an input HTML element as ibxFile
    var ibxFile = document.createElement("INPUT");
    // set the type of the HTML element to "file"
    ibxFile.setAttribute("type", "file");
    // set the id fo the HTML element to "inputFile"
    ibxFile.setAttribute("id", "inputFile");
    ibxFile.setAttribute("multiple", "multiple");

    // append the ibxFile element to the body of this HTML page
    document.body.appendChild(ibxFile);

    document.getElementById("inputFile").addEventListener('change', fileChangeHandler);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```